# Example of sequentially compact Lindelof space being noncompact

Tags: general-topology

Is there an example of topological space being both sequentially compact and Lindelof but noncompact?

Comment: Welcome to this new forum. Please listen that this is not Q&A site. So you to show your primary thinking about you question and show that you have tried it. Then others will help you to boost your thinking.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Let $X$ be a sequentially compact and Lindelöf topological space. Then $X$ is countably compact, since it is sequentially compact. (*) It is  by definition that countably compact and Lindelöf space is compact.

(*) Countably compactness is equivalent to the following: "For arbitrary sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, the set $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\overline{\{ x_n, x_{n+1},\cdots \}}$ is not empty." (This can be proven immediately by definition of countably compactness, using easy set-theoretic calculation.) You can now show that sequentially compactness implies countablly compactness.

Comment: Than You very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such space. Indeed,
every [sequentially compact space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space) is [countably compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countably_compact_space). And a countably compact space is compact if and only if it is Lindelöf.

Comment: Thank You very much! I see my question was stupid

Answer (score 0):

We know every sequentially compact space is Countably compact. And we also know countably compact $+$ Lindeloff space means Compact space. So we don't have an example of your question.

See, page $2$ graph, [here](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.uwm.edu/dist/0/158/files/2016/10/751.F10.IIIB-C-16qokmp.pdf)

Comment: Thank You! I had to look around a little before asking.

Comment: @NurlanAbiev, as you are new in this forum. So i am telling the rule. If you like an answer helpful,you can vote it up by clicking the $\text{up arrow}$ as you see in the left side of the answer.